# How to use issorted function to check if the array is sorted in descending order

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use `issorted` function to check if the array is sorted in descending order but it only works for ascending order .. I used `fliplr` function before checking the order and it works fine but I don't know if there is a more efficient solution or not .. Any Help?

My Code:

```
a = [1 2 3 4];
fliplr(a);
s = issorted(a);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fliplr` does only this:

```
if ~ismatrix(x)
  error(message('MATLAB:fliplr:SizeX')); 
end
y = x(:,end:-1:1);
```

so you could speed up your code a little by just doing `y = x(:,end:-1:1);` instead of executing `fliplr`. You could also try @kmundnic suggestion, but it wont work when `a` is cell of strings, and `issorted` can operate on the cell of strings as well.

Answer (score 5):

What about negating a? It should be faster than fliplr(a).

```
a = -2:4;
s = issorted(-a);
```

Answer (score 2):

For a numeric vector, this should be pretty fast:

```
s = all(diff(a)<=0);
```

Or perhaps

```
isempty(find(diff(a)>0,1))
```

so that `find` can stop as soon as it finds an pair of values.